# can a Web Workers file handle includes or modules?

Tags: javascript, module, web-worker

I have several `web worker`s, each supporting different tables in the database. Each of `web worker` uses a core set of functions (for accessing the server, querying, etc).

What is the best means for putting these shared, common fuctions into the several `web worker`s?

it seems that if they are loaded as files, then the browser will have them cached and the workers themselves can be lighter.

perhaps they could be loaded as `es6` `modules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web workers receive a global function, `importScripts` ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#dom-workerglobalscope-importscripts) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts)), that you can use to import scripts into the worker's global context:

```
importScripts('shared.js');
```

Someday, I'm sure we'll be able to use ES2015 (ES6) modules, but that day will likely be at least a year or two from now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Also note that [`RequireJS`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) works in web workers so if you use that for your app, you can easily have dependencies resolved.